# Eclipse Oxygen 3.a not working MacOS Big Sur java 1.8.0_271

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-big-sur

I just updated to Big Sur and I cannot start my eclipse 3.a.
First it failed to start, then I added the following to the start paramters:

```
    <string>-vm</string>enter code here<string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>    
<string>-keyring</string>
e<string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
```

but now the window is completely invisible. I don't know what to do anymore and I need it to work on monday.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen.3a then

Answer (score 2):

My Info.plist is as below.

```
        <array>
            <!-- to use a specific Java version (instead of the platform's default) uncomment one of the following options,
                    or add a VM found via $/usr/libexec/java_home -V
                <string>-vm</string><string>/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Commands/java</string>
                <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
            -->
            <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
            <string>-keyring</string>
            <string>~/.eclipse_keyring</string>
        </array>
```

The main thing is, **`disconnect your external monitor`**.

Comment: Not sure why the disconnect monitor, but did help; thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. near unusable; artifacts are not being refreshed in the window.